# Uncopyable object, map and shared_ptr : error in the copy constructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have an issue constructing my non-copyable object . Let consider the following example :

```
class Uncopyable{
protected:
    Uncopyable(){};
    ~Uncopyable(){};

private:
    Uncopyable(const Uncopyable&);
    Uncopyable& operator=(const Uncopyable&);
};


class Base { };
class Derived : public Base { };

class A : private Uncopyable {
public:
    A(std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> & inMap);
private:
    A(const A&);
    A& operator=(const A&);
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>> lMap;
    std::shared_ptr<A> oA(std::make_shared<A>(lMap));
}
```

If I assume my object A to be non-copyable , it does not work.As a pointer, I expect my object A to understand that Derived is a Base, but instead I am getting the following message:

```
error C2664: 'A::A(const A &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Derived>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' to 'std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Base>,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<Derived>
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>  ,            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<Base>
1>          ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with `A`'s noncopyability and indeed is not in the copy constructor - it's in the `map` constructor. The error has to do with the fact that `A'` constructor takes a

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> &
```

and you are passing a:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>
```

An argument that is an lvalue reference of type `T` can only be satisfied by an lvalue of type `T` or of a type derived from `T` (or of a type with an `operator T&`). But `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Derived>>` does not actually inherit from `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>>` - nor are the two types related at all - there is no cross-type constructor for `std::map`.

In other words, just because a `D` is a `B` doesn't mean that a `map<X, D>` is a `map<X, B>`. There is no covariance of types in the C++ type system in this way. Some types at least allow you to construct a `Class<B>` from a `Class<D>` (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`), but that's not true of the standard containers (e.g. `vector`, `map`, ...)

You will have to change `lMap` to hold `std::shared_ptr<Base>`s in order for this to work. It can internally hold `std::shared_ptr<Derived>`s - but the `map` types have to match.

---

Side-note, in C++11 you don't need `Uncopyable`. You can simply explicitly `delete` those operations:

```
A(A const& ) = delete;
A& operator=(A const& ) = delete;
```

Comment: I see you point, it is very clear.
So if a function f takes as an argument an std::shared_ptr<Derived>, and I define  std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base>> lMap. I assign to lMap[0]  an std::shared_ptr<Derived>. It will not be possible to use lMap[0] to f ?

Comment: @Canardini If `f` takes a `shared_ptr<Derived>`, then you cannot pass a `shared_ptr<Base>` to it, yes. How would it know that it actually points to a `Derived` object?

Comment: Right, this is what I understood from your answer. I tried to use dynamic cast pointer , it could not solve the issue .